# Curl and post it in table

Tags: php, curl

So yesterday i asked about posting data into a table. Now it does give a good result but it takes at least 30 seconds to get the result. I tried it with curl and i get a result almost instant. Now my question is : How do i Post data from curl into a table.

My code :

```
function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

print curl_download('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=1&alpha=a&page=1');
```

With as result :

> {"total":5,"items":[{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=4798","id":4798,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant brutal","description":"Blunt adamantite arrow...ouch","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":222},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=810","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=810","id":810,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant dart","description":"A deadly throwing dart with an adamant tip.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":11},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=829","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=829","id":829,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant javelin","description":"An adamant tipped javelin.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":64},"today":{"trend":"positive","price":"+1"}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=867","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=867","id":867,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant knife","description":"A finely balanced throwing knife.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":23},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=804","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=804","id":804,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant throwing axe","description":"A finely balanced throwing axe.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":180},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}}]}

I have tried google but because my knowledge about curl and array's is zero i don't got any further.

Comment: By Post it in table, do you just want to render a table with the data fetched back?

Comment: @MajorCaiger I don't exactly know what you mean but this was the result of yesterday after my question was answered : http://puu.sh/3UfYe.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response looks like json, so you could try the following.

EDIT:

This works fine for me.

```
<?php

$response = '{"total":5,"items":[{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=4798","id":4798,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant brutal","description":"Blunt adamantite arrow...ouch","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":222},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=810","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=810","id":810,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant dart","description":"A deadly throwing dart with an adamant tip.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":11},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=829","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=829","id":829,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant javelin","description":"An adamant tipped javelin.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":64},"today":{"trend":"positive","price":"+1"}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=867","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=867","id":867,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant knife","description":"A finely balanced throwing knife.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":23},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}},{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_sprite.gif?id=804","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4173_obj_big.gif?id=804","id":804,"type":"Ammo","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo","name":"Adamant throwing axe","description":"A finely balanced throwing axe.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":180},"today":{"trend":"neutral","price":0}}]}';

$data = json_decode( $response, true );

?>
<table>
    <?php
    foreach( $data['items'] as $row )
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $row['icon']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

In your example response would be the return value from curl_download

```
$response = curl_download('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/items.json?category=1&alpha=a&page=1');
```

Comment: Getting the following error : Warning: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in` on the line ` foreach( $data['items'] as $row )
`

Comment: @JacobBrol Are you passing true in as a second argument of json_decode? You might need to var_dump $data to see what your array looks like after json_decode

Comment: @JacobBrol I have updated my answer with a clearer example, hope this helps